# File Not Found Exception in HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android

I want to show the **image** in **ImageView** Android. The url of the image is http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg

But this **url is not accessible** in android using **HttpUrlConnection**. It gave me a **FileNotFoundException**.
The url is successfully accessible in **Chrome** and on **Postman** .

> Code

```
class GetData extends AsyncTask <String,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String result = "";
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg");
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                if (in != null) {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        result += line;
                }
                in.close();
                return result;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if(conn!=null)
                conn.disconnect();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}
```

I don't know why it gave Exception in HttpUrlConnection.

> StackTrace

```
12-17 21:07:15.752: W/System.err(2129): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg
12-17 21:07:15.752: W/System.err(2129):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
12-17 21:07:15.752: W/System.err(2129):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:80)
12-17 21:07:15.752: W/System.err(2129):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-17 21:07:15.752: W/System.err(2129):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
12-17 21:07:15.752: W/System.err(2129):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-17 21:07:15.752: W/System.err(2129):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-17 21:07:15.752: W/System.err(2129):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-17 21:07:15.752: W/System.err(2129):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-17 21:07:15.752: W/System.err(2129):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have also tried.

```
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
conn.setDoOutput(false);
```

But no luck.
If anyone has ever faced this issue, please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. This would include the source code where you are using `HttpUrlConnection`, plus the full stack trace.

Comment: "The url is successfully accessible in Chrome" -- did you try this on the device or emulator that you are using for testing your app? Do you have the `INTERNET` permission?

Comment: Maybe you forget to send some important **http-headers (like user-agent)**, needed/checked by the webserver? Chrome (and so on) will send such headers....

Comment: yes, it it accessible in `emulator` and i also have Internet Permission in `Manifest`

Comment: BTW: Save LINK/URL (from Browser) will return an HTML-Document, not an JPEG-Image

Comment: But it is giving me a jpg image.

Comment: Try it, maybe the webserver is doing some kind of re-directing.You can see it, when you open the URL in an browser. You can see that **not only the image** is shown, also some HTML-Stuff (like: **World Sunlight Map**)! Try this address:**http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1152.jpg**